# Internal left knee pain causing muscles imbalance

Tags: workout-routines, workout, stretching, knees, knee-pain

I have been doing Tae Bo workout for about one year while having internal left knee injury. Actually,It is not so painful when doing squats or kicks, but I feel the pain when I do leg launches exercices.

Unfortunately, now I feel like I have muscles imbalance causing by my left knee injury. What I have tried so far is to never do leg launches exercices for both knees.

So here come my questions:

- How to get my muscles balance back?
- Is there any routine stretches to fix my left knee pain?

Thanks.

Comment: If you've had pain for a year, I would see a doctor. That's not normal.

Comment: Agreed, if you have an actual injury you need to see a doctor.

Knee pain is often caused by tight or insufficient hip/glute mobility and strength. Look into foam rolling them legs and targeting those muscle groups to see if that gives you relief.

Comment: I just want to recommend [this](http://www.runningwritings.com/2011/09/injury-series-tendon-remodeling-part-ii.html) article because it helped me.